# QueryStringField of DataPager and ASP.NET Page Route?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, routes, datapager

I am using QueryStringField to of DataPager to show page number in url. Work fines.
But i don't want the name of field to be shown in url. what i tired is

Global File Code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("xyz", "Test/TestRoutes/{PageId}", "~/Demo1.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary { { "PageId", "1" } });
    }
```

and in html i wrote for DataPager.

```
 <asp:DataPager ID="ProductListPagerComboTop" runat="server" PagedControlID="lv1"
        PageSize="5" QueryStringField="PageId">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="false" ButtonCssClass="pagerButton"
                FirstPageText="&lt;&lt;" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" />
            <asp:NumericPagerField CurrentPageLabelCssClass="pagerButtonCurrentPage" RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="false"
                NextPreviousButtonCssClass="pagerButton" NumericButtonCssClass="pagerButton" />
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="false" ButtonCssClass="pagerButton"
                LastPageText="&gt;&gt;" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

So the url generated is :

```
http://localhost:2055/Test/TestRoutes?PageId=2
```

where as i want.

```
http://localhost:2055/Test/TestRoutes/2
```

How to do this?

Comment: hi if your problem is solved using any of the reference below mark the the replies as answer by click a tick below each answers and you can also vote up the answers by clicking the up arrow in the left side of each answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL Rewrite module on the IIS.

Comment: Please provide detailed research and information when you're providing an answer

Answer (score 0):

You try re-writing your URL here.

ScottG'S Blog is best to understand this concept.

Refer below URL:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: There you go with another reference site for URL routing and rewritting [Click here for reference](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx)